# Trajectory of projectile slightly off Unity2D

Tags: unity-game-engine, projectile

I have a simple cannon I am trying to program to shoot a projectile. I have 4 game objects:

- The tank object
- A Pivot Object (child of tank)
- A Cannon Object (child of pivot)
- An empty GameObject called Tip which sits just above the cannon (child of cannon)

My code for the cannon object is below:

```
public class cannon: MonoBehaviour
{ 
    public float power = 1.0f;
    public Transform projectile;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        {
            Transform bullet;
            Vector2 pos = transform.GetChild(0).position;
            bullet = Instantiate(projectile, pos, Quaternion.identity);
            Rigidbody2D bullet_rb = bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
            bullet_rb.AddForce(pos * power);
        }
    }
}
```

Everything seems to work okay, until I looked at the trajectory of the projectiles when the cannon is aimed directly along the x-axis. There is still a small y component to the applied force, which I didn't expect and do not desire.

Here's a gif:

[image]

What could be causing this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The force you're adding is `pos` (times a scalar `power`)... The position of your cannon is above zero on the y axis, so that's why it launches with a y offset. I'm assuming it has an x offset too, just less noticeable, because the base (`tank`) is centered at x while it's above center in the y. Try moving the whole tank setup off away from the scene root; you'll probably see a huge spike in the force of the projectile, because of this error of using `pos`.

What you want is a vector representing a pure **direction** instead. One that is also **normalized** (magnitude of one). In this case, either `right` (forward in 2d) or `up`, from the perspective of the rotating `tip` or `cannon`.

Comment: I tried using `bullet.up` as the argument of `AddForce` but when I do that, there is only ever a y component of force added so the projectiles simply launch vertically from the tip regardless of the angle.

Comment: Nevermind, I just realized I should use the transform of the cannon or tip since I instantiate with identity rotation

Comment: @AlexEshoo It's not a bad idea to rotate the projectile to the source's (in this case `tip`'s) rotation on spawn. It won't make a visual difference in this case, since your projectile is a ball, but it will if you ever change it to an elongated shape like a cilinder (often used as a lit "tracer") or a bullet. It's a good habit, plus you can then base your direction on the projectile's forward direction, which is more readable/intuitive (you're not dealing with the source of the animore after the projectile is spawned).